# Uso de Pilha String em C, Alocação dinâmica e Ponteiro

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, malloc

Não estou conseguindo imprimir além de 1 caractere e não consigo pensar Aonde se usa corretamente malloc. A ideia correta é usar alocação dinâmica e ponteiros. Por fim, precisa armazenar cada elemento no vetor e imprimir. Eu poderia ter criado uma função de impressão ao fim do preenchimento. Temi que a alocação dinâmica/ponteiro acabasse zerando ou apagando algo e, fiz `printf` a cada chamada de `void empilha` ~__^.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#define TAMANHO_PILHA 5


typedef struct {

    char vetorPilha[TAMANHO_PILHA]; 

    int topo;

} Pilha;


void empilha(char *valor, Pilha *pilha){  //*deu certo mas imprime 1° caractere só *
    
    if(pilha->topo<TAMANHO_PILHA){

    pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo] = *valor;
    
    printf("%c\n", pilha->vetorPilha[pilha->topo]);
    
    pilha->topo++; 
    } else {
        printf("Nao ha espaco\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 
    Pilha p;
    
    p.topo = 0;
    
    empilha("Primeiro",&p);   //elemento 1 [0]
    
    empilha("Segundo",&p);
    
    empilha("Terceiro",&p);
    
    empilha("Quarto",&p);
    
    empilha("Quinto",&p);  //elemento 5 [4]
    
    //aqui eu acredito que poderia chamar uma funcao de impressao quando vetorPilha estivesse preenchido

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quando você faz `*valor` em:

```
   pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo] = *valor;
```

Você está pegando apenas o primeiro caractere. A string é um conjunto de caracteres (que termina no nulo). Ele começa de algum lugar, e exatametne onde ele começa é a primeira letra. Se você faz `*valor` você está pegando o primeiro valor e só.

Usando o `char *` você vai armazenar o endereço da memoria onde a string começa, consequentemente conseguirá ler o texto inteiro.

---

Então, o que deve fazer, é usar `char * vetorPilha[TAMANHO_PILHA]`. Depois, simplesmente dar um `malloc`, copiar o texto, e usa-lo:

```
void empilha(char *valor, Pilha *pilha){  //*deu certo mas imprime 1° caractere só *
    if(pilha->topo<TAMANHO_PILHA){
        pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo] = (char *) realloc(pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo], strlen(valor) + 1);
        memcpy(pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo], valor, strlen(valor) + 1);

        printf("%s\n", pilha->vetorPilha[pilha->topo]);

        pilha->topo++;
    } else {
        printf("Nao ha espaco\n");
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, criamos um novo espaço de memoria (ou não, se não for necessário), e então copiamos a string para este espaço.

Também é usado o `%s`, ao invés de `%c`.

Você pode simplesmente fazer:

```
    if(pilha->topo<TAMANHO_PILHA){
        pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo] = valor

        printf("%s\n", pilha->vetorPilha[pilha->topo]);

        pilha->topo++;
    } else {
        printf("Nao ha espaco\n");
    }
```

*Sem a necessidade de tal alocação. Porém, eu ACREDITO que isso pode quebrar caso esteja passando ponteiros criados numa função local, por via das duvidas, copie.*

---

No final:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANHO_PILHA 5

typedef struct {
    char * vetorPilha[TAMANHO_PILHA]; //tamanho da pilha
    int topo;
} Pilha;


void empilha(char *valor, Pilha *pilha){  //*deu certo mas imprime 1° caractere só *
    if(pilha->topo<TAMANHO_PILHA){
        pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo] = (char *) realloc(pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo], strlen(valor) + 1);
        memcpy(pilha->vetorPilha[pilha-> topo], valor, strlen(valor) + 1);

        printf("%s\n", pilha->vetorPilha[pilha->topo]);
        pilha->topo++;
    } else {
        printf("Nao ha espaco\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Pilha p;

    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(Pilha));

    empilha("Primeiro",&p);   //elemento 1 [0]
    empilha("Segundo",&p);
    empilha("Terceiro",&p);
    empilha("Quarto",&p);
    empilha("Quinto",&p);  //elemento 5 [4]

    return 0;
}
```

Isto imprime:

```
Primeiro
Segundo
Terceiro
Quarto
Quinto
```

Comment: Eu sou muito grato pq eu jamais tiraria essa conclusao sozinho, fiquei muitas horas no domingo tentando - que nao deram nenhum resultado. Eu nao sei por que imprimiu Primeiro Segundo [fim] se eu chamei as 5 vezes. O memset vc recomendou pra outra questao parecida aqui, nao seria a falta disso que está enchendo a memoria?

Comment: Corrigi o problema. A questão era que o código original só definia `p.topo = 0`, mas não inicializava as outras coisas. Adicionei um `memset(&p, 0, sizeof(Pilha));` para que todo o conteúdo dentro do `p Pilha` seja zero.

Comment: O gente melhorem a pergunta, não está legal dessa forma.

Comment: @AugustoVasques acho que é melhor fechar. ou negativar, já nem to ligando mais. 

Comment: É justamente isso que queria evitar.

Comment: Eu queria pagar mas ngm faz isso por menos de 50 reais. Nao na plataforma profes nem na superprof. Existe uma taxa de entrada.

Comment: Dado o contexto eu nao pude escolher C ou a linguagem que eu conhecia pra entregar essa atividade - simplesmente empurraram C e ponto final. Ainda tem mais coisa pra fazer que eu nao postei, pq eu mesmo vou tentar pra depois vir aqui dnv (ou pagar R$70 no minimo). Eu entendo que seja inacreditavel pra alguem no nivel de vcs crer q alguem fica horas na frente de algo e nao consegue - pq justamente eu avancei muito ao tentar usar ponteiros. Entre inumeras possibilidades de uso do memset eu nao acertaria a combinaçao e/ou a posição q o Inkeliz indicou. O certo era eu pagar tutoria? isso ne :/

Comment: @KianuRivsSmurf ninguém está pedindo para pagar. As pessoas do SO respondem voluntariamente, e a unica cosia que ganhamos são pontos (quando você vota positivamente numa pergunta/resposta ganhamos uns pontinhos, este que fica no nome). O problema é que sua pergunta não é válida para o SO. Em tese, eu nem deveria de responder, já que não faz parte do escopo. O que foi comentado pelo Augusto, é de melhorar a sua pergunta, alterar o titulo e deixar o problema mais claro, para que outras pessoas possam ser ajudadas e encontrar esta sua pergunta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8725/15089

Answer (score 0):

Para responder ao teu problema de porquê só imprimir o primeiro caracter, não podes copiar uma palavra utilizando o sinal de atribuição igual "=".

Utilizando a função `strcpy` da biblioteca <string.h> (é preciso fazer o `#include <string.h>`) resolves facilmente o problema modificando apenas duas linhas do teu código:

```
void empilha(char *valor, Pilha *pilha) {
    if (pilha->topo < TAMANHO_PILHA) {
        strcpy(pilha->vetorPilha, valor);
        printf("%s\n", pilha->vetorPilha);
        pilha->topo++; 
    } else {
        printf("Nao ha espaco\n");
    }
}
```

No entanto, não resolve a questão principal que é a utilização de uma pilha dinâmica. Nesse caso a pilha deveria ser implementada utilizando uma estrutura semelhante à de uma lista ligada, que recomendo a pesquisa e estudo de como implementar, pois é uma matéria demasiado vasta para uma simples resposta aqui.
Um exemplo de implementação seria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char palavra[64];
    struct node *next; 
} NODE;

NODE *top = NULL;

void inserirNaPilha(char palavra[]) {
    NODE *newNode = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(newNode->palavra, palavra);
    if (top == NULL) {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        top = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode->next = top;
        top = newNode;
    }
}

void mostrarPilha() {
    NODE *aux;
    aux = top;
    if (top == NULL) {
        printf("Pilha Vazia\n");
    } else {
        while (aux != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", aux->palavra);
            aux = aux->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    inserirNaPilha("Primeiro");
    inserirNaPilha("Segundo");
    inserirNaPilha("Terceiro");
    inserirNaPilha("Quarto");
    inserirNaPilha("Quinto");
    mostrarPilha();
    return 0;
}
```